# Cloud webservice for and Android app

Tags: mysql, web-services, rest, cloud

Hello I'm looking for a freeware or cheap server where I can set up a RESTful webservice with database and php.

Does anyone suggest me a good one?

Thanks!

Comment: Try [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/pricing.html), the 1 GB plan is free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.firebase.com/features.html

**FireBase** is a great option (*I recommend this one*). you can do authentication (g+, Twitter,Facebook, password based and anonymous), Realtime Database and hosting. 
the free teir is pretty good, but it can get expensive.

http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/couchbase-server

You can also use **CouchBase server** but you need to do a lot of set ups for it. its free!